# How to specify Cedar to use ree 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, cedar

I am running a rails 2.3.16 app on Heroku with ruby 1.8.7.

I know that I should upgrade to rails 3 but until I have more time I would like to use REE 1.8.7 instead of MRI 1.8.7 on my Heroku app. It appears that Cedar supports REE based on:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack

I am specifying my ruby version in my Gemfile with

ruby "1.8.7"

I thought I might be able to do it with specifying an engine:

ruby "1.8.7", :engine => "ree", :engine_version => "2012.02"

But that didn't end up working for obvious reasons after I tried it.

I would love to run ree even though it has reached end of life support until I can upgrade due to all the security and performance gains.

Is running ruby 1.8.7 on cedar automatically running ree?

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Cedar does not have REE 1.8.7 installed but you should be able to use 1.8.7 MRI by having

```
ruby "1.8.7"
```

in your Gemfile. You can read more about this on the Heroku site at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration but they are encouraging you to use 1.9.2 I'm afraid.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack seems to indicate that they do support REE 1.8.7 is there an issue with their documentation?

Comment: those are old stacks that used to supporr 1.8.7. You can only provision new apps on Cedar these days.